# My comment was deleted

Tags: support, deleted-comments

Refer to this question: [Possible Bug in SpringMVC: Cannot handle servlet paths like / or /*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955820/possible-bug-in-springmvc-cannot-handle-servlet-paths-like-or?noredirect=1#comment40695711_25955820)

One of the comments I posted was deleted, and I was given no notification that it was deleted.  I don't know who did it or why.

What's worse, is that somebody is saying I'm wrong in a follow-up comment and I can't retort because my original comment is gone.  This is incredibly frustrating, what can I do?

How can I ask a question directly to the administrators of the site?

How can I see who deleted my comment? Why? And what the comment was before it was deleted?

Comment: Give us a link to the message saying you're wrong. That would be a good start. In any case, questions _about_ SO belong on Meta.

Comment: Unless it was a comment, you should be able to see your deleted content.  If it was a question, you may need a direct URL to the post.  It may be under "recently deleted" in your question list, or you may find it in your browser history.

Comment: I asked this question by going to the help center, I wanted to email them directly but this was all they offered from that page.  It's not fair to blame me for how this was categorized.  I don't think it's fair to down vote this and damage my reputation because I wanted to ask SO a question directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955820/possible-bug-in-springmvc-cannot-handle-servlet-paths-like-or?noredirect=1#comment40695711_25955820

Comment: What's the content of your deleted comment? I guess it's flagged and then deleted.

Comment: @Matthew Lundberg, it was not a question that was deleted, it was two of the messages I posted on it.

Comment: @Yu Hao, are you asking for a general idea?  or the exact text?  it was deleted so I just remember saying that the spring DispatcherServlet is supposed to handle JSP or something like that.

Comment: This comment makes me think that your deleted comments were less-than-useful: "why does nobody ever want to admit that their tutorials and documentation are unclear? Don't you remember how much you struggled to learn these things? Just write some decent documentation in the first place so you stop wasting everybodys time."

Comment: look at the second comment on the question, it starts with "in fact", what am I saying in fact to?  It makes no sense because the comment I had before it is gone now, and the guy responded to the comment I made.  I can't retort because the comment is gone.

Comment: Re: *I don't think it's fair to down vote this and damage my reputation*, because you posted it on the wrong site (main SO site), and it has been migrated to the correct site (meta SO). Re: this issue, I believe someone flagged your comment as not constructive/offensive. Btw, only mods can see deleted comment, so we can only wait.

Comment: @Andrew T. I went to the help center and this was all they offered, if you did not expect somebody to ask for help from the help center then why did they name it the help center?

Comment: If you can't retort, then _don't._ Based on the initial tone of your question and all the comments I've seen from you, I'd say you were spoiling for a fight from the get go, but I've been wrong before, as my wife will point out, quickly and without much encouragement :-) That's not a good position to be taking when you're asking for help. My advice would be to suck it up and move on. Try to clarify exactly what you need in the question _now_ and people will be more than willing to help. In other words, step back. You can argue and complain all day but that won't get your question answered.

Comment: @paxdiablo, what I'm trying to do, is convince people that they need to update their documentation.  I think people are arguing with me because they don't want to admit that any of their work is inadequate.

Comment: Then say it once and move on. SO is not a soapbox where you try to convince people to do things, however worthwhile those things may be. It's a Q&A site. FWIW, I've pinged a moderator to see if they can look into it but they're busy people at the best of times so, like the supreme court, they may even refuse to get involved :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, I would not have used SO in that manner if I had any other way to contact Spring.  Their forum is now read-only, and they have no email address.  Their questions page takes people to SO, it's as if they are trying to pass SO for their own site.  This is basically the only way I can talk to them.

Comment: @msknapp That is, unfortunately, Spring's fault and Spring's problem. Their misuse of SO doesn't allow you to try to contact them through here. They're essentially misusing SO by cutting off any other form of contact. For the record, there is a [hard-to-find contact form](http://www.pivotal.io/contact/spring-support) that appears to be free, even though it's located under 'Professional Support' on their page.

Comment: "somebody is saying I'm wrong in a follow-up comment" -- if they address your deleted comment, you just flag this follow-up comment as obsolete and moderator will wipe it out (or, if more users notice this and also flag obsolete, it will be removed automatically)

Answer (score 3):

Your original comment was this:

> I don't understand what you mean by template resolution, but I will repeat that DispatcherServlet often returns a view that is a JSP, your claim that it can't handle JSP is false.

which was flagged as being rude, as part of couple other flags being cast on that question. A moderator saw that, as well as a rudeness flag on this comment:

> @M. Deinum, your claims don't make sense, you say it can't really handle a JSP, but it does all the time! In fact that is the normal way things work, the controller specifies a view, and that view is a JSP file. The way I see it, the filter is given a request either way, whether it was mapped through / or /*, it should be able to handle that. The servlet spec says /* is allowed, so spring should support it. Call it what you want to, a bug, a behaviour, I don't care, the fact is it's wrong and spring is to blame. There is no reason it should not have been able to handle that request.

and removed those comments. In my opinion, these comments aren't too bad, so I've undeleted at least the first one.

If I had to guess, I'd say that they removed the flagged comment in an attempt to prevent this argument from escalating. As others have commented, you appear to want to have an extended argument about this in comments, which really aren't the place for something like this. I'd recommend taking a heated back-and-forth like this out of comments and into a chatroom or some other offline discussion.

Comments on Stack Overflow are primarily for supplemental information relevant to the post they are placed on, and are ephemeral by design. They are not the place to have extended discussions, which might be different from other sites you're used to.

Comment: he is saying it's rude just because it disagrees with him, which is not a valid reason to delete my comment.  A rude comment would have used curse words or insulted him specifically, I did not do that.  Instead, I offered a logical explanation why I disagreed, so it should not have been deleted.  I made a valid point that his explanation does not make sense.  I don't think it's right to delete a comment just because it disagrees with somebody.  Also, there is no spring chatroom afaik, spring has made it impossible to contact them directly.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `off-site discussion` rather than `offline discussion`?